# WebView link to launch Safari?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I am using UI webview in xcode in my iphone mobile application..i am loading my website in webview but all link in website like(facebook,twitter,youtube etc..)are open in same webview not in mobile safari..

please suggest me how to do it

thanks in advance

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899699/uiwebview-open-links-in-safari

Comment: can i do it in javascript or in HTML instead of xcode??

Comment: what do you mean with "xcode"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see: [UIWebView Launch in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880620/uiwebview-launch-in-safari)

you need to examine the url to see if it belongs to facebook,twitter,youtube etc and if so launch accordingly

```
-(BOOL) adBox:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest            
                                         navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {


   if (![inRequest.URL.host isEqualToString:@"www.mydomain.com"]) { //Test if it's NOT my site
       if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
           return NO; //Open in Safair
       }
     }

   return YES; //Open in UIWebView

 }
```

Comment: Just test to see if the request is not of your domain. See my edit

Comment: this delegate function is working fine in html anchor click but it will work on window.open() method also?please help